# Facebook sdk for android. How to get signed_request?

Tags: android, facebook

Is there any way to get signed_request with Facebook sdk for Android. Or the only way is to build it manually?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: I didn't found any information specifically for android (java) only for php. I rewrote php  function to java function in order to generate signed_request by myself, but maybe there is more beautiful and ready solution inside Facebook SDK and I just can't find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [signed_request field](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/) is POSTed to your server when a user loads your Canvas and Page Tab App on Facebook.com, it's not relevant to native mobile apps