# Authenticating user through facebook login in Java server

Tags: java, android, facebook, security, google-app-engine

I'm not really sure on how to go about this, so i will just explain what i am trying to do.

I have built a REST API for my mobile app, in the client side the user would log in with facebook, and afterwards would make requests to my own REST server, with actions such uploading pictures and updating location.

When i did this in PHP the user would send the access token + details such as mail with every request and i would use the access token to verify the details correspond, that was my basic security measure (you can probably guess I'm not a security expert)

This seemed like a good idea at the time, but since then i moved my server to google app engine using Java, so I was wondering how can I do that in java, and if this is a good idea in general, or maybe I should take a different approach?

Any answers would be welcome!

Comment: you are looking for a new solution rather than just porting the PHP code to Java?

Comment: i was wondering if this is the right way to do it, and if so, how to do this in Java, since Facebook doesn't have an SDK for Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I needed to implement this a few years ago, I tried two basic approaches.

Easy approach, but doesn't scale very well: Used [RestFB](http://restfb.com/) and initiated a DefaultFacebookClient using the access token, then compared the information on that client with the username that my client sent with the token.  The reason that this doesn't scale is that it requires an HTTP or HTTPS call to Facebook, which can take several seconds.  That kills performance if you have a lot of users logging in at the same time.

The more complicated approach used examples provided by [ptarjan](https://github.com/ptarjan/signed-request).  The crucial part I used was this (don't recall whether it is unchanged from ptarjan's version):

```
    public static SignedRequestResponse parse_signed_request(String input, String secret, int max_age) {
        String[] split = input.split("[.]", 2);
        SignedRequestResponse response = new SignedRequestResponse();
        response.setStatus(Status.Failure);

        String encoded_sig = split[0];
        String encoded_envelope = split[1];
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Map envelope;
        try {
            envelope = (Map) parser.parse(new String(base64_url_decode(encoded_envelope)));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            response.addError("ParsingError");
            return response;
        }

        response.setEnvelope(envelope);

        String algorithm = (String) envelope.get("algorithm");

        if (!algorithm.equals("HMAC-SHA256")) {
            response.addError("UnsupportedAlgorithm");
            return response;    // instant fail
        }

        byte[] key = secret.getBytes();
        SecretKey hmacKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "HMACSHA256");
        Mac mac = null;
        try {
            mac = Mac.getInstance("HMACSHA256");
            mac.init(hmacKey);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.addError("DecryptionError");
            return response; // instant fail
        }

        byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(encoded_envelope.getBytes());
        try {

            if (!Arrays.equals(base64_url_decode(encoded_sig), digest)) {
                response.addError("InvalidSignature");
                return response; // instant fail
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            response.addError("InvalidSignature");
            return response; // instant fail
        }

        if (((Long) envelope.get("issued_at")) < System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 - max_age) {
            response.addError("Expired");
            response.setStatus(Status.PartialSuccess);
            return response;    // partial fail
        }

        response.setStatus(Status.Success);
        return response;
    }
}
```

The secret variable is the app secret key.

Comment: How do you get the signed request in a mobile application?

Comment: That comes with the token, doesn't it?  If it doesn't, see if this post helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456829/provide-secure-facebook-authentication-with-my-server?rq=1

Comment: I think Facebook only POSTs the signed request to Canvas or Page Tab apps. The RestFB lib sounds like it will help OP tho.

Comment: thanks for the answer but honestly i don't have enough knowledge to understand this :P
could you explain what is the difference in the second approach? 
and do you know what is the lowest level approach to do this? performance is important in my case

Comment: In the second approach, the client uses its own Facebook API (whichever one it used to log in to Facebook in the first place) to ask for the signed request.  It sends that signed request to the server.  The server then uses the above code to verify that the signed request is legitimate, without needing to make a call to Facebook.  This means it takes nanoseconds instead of needing to make an HTTP call.

Comment: If it helps, I have a full open source project for doing that second approach on the server side, with a Javascript + AS3 client communicating using ElectroServer5.  Not sure whether that would be helpful or just confusing.

Comment: ok after reading a bit about signed request i think i understand everything, although i'm guessing its less secured, it will probably be enough for what i need right now
thanks you! :)

Comment: ok one more question, this is a mobile, and as i understand from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119979/facebook-sdk-for-android-how-to-get-signed-request) it cannot be obtained in the android SDK, so how did you do it?

Comment: After refreshing my memory on the project, the signed request version was only used for the web app.  The android and ios apps sent an access token and the server then validated it using RestFB.

Comment: i see, so did you find a way to validate it on the server side alone? or did you have to create a facebook client on the server?
performance is important in my case and users need to send constant updates on their location every few seconds.
can you think of a better way to make this somewhat secured?

Comment: In that project, the users were logging in to a socket server.  One thing you could try doing is either storing the validated access token on the server and when the client sends the same token a few seconds later you know it is good because you had validated it recently.  Another option is to create your own token for the validated user to use for subsequent requests.

Comment: wow thats a good idea, sounds perfect actually, thank you very much :)

Comment: @DanLevin do you have an open source project with the solution you crated ? or any other way to share it. thanks

Comment: @Amitk Hey, it's been a while since i posted this question. unfortunately no it's been too long :) what ever i solution i found it's probably outdated